# Android - Populate recycler view problems

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have done something doing that when arraylist.day == calendar.dayofmonth, it programmatically scroll into the arraylist position but when i start my activity i've got this error : "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference".

Can someone help me please ?

Planning.java :

```
    public void setUpRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

private void setUpFirebase(){
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}

private void loadDataFromFirebase(){
    if(eventsArrayList.size()>0){
        eventsArrayList.clear();}
    db.collection("Planning").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot: task.getResult()){
                Events Nom = new Events(querySnapshot.getString("Nom"),querySnapshot.getString("Lieu"),querySnapshot.getString("Heure"),querySnapshot.getString("Minute"),querySnapshot.getString("Day"));
                eventsArrayList.add(Nom);
            }
            tvLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Planning.this, eventsArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        }
}

    public void ScrollTo(int position){
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
}
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter :

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    holder.tvLieu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.tvNom.getLayoutParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.START;
    holder.tvNom.setLayoutParams(params);
    if(eventsArrayList.get(position).getDay().equals(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) { planning.ScrollTo(position); }
    holder.tvNom.setText(eventsArrayList.get(position).getNom());
    holder.tvLieu.setText(eventsArrayList.get(position).getLieu());
    holder.tvDate.setText(eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure() + "h" + eventsArrayList.get(position).getMinute());
    if(eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure().equals("")){
        holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvLieu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        holder.tvNom.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#227c97"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a proper stack trace, I could only assume either `eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure()` or  `eventsArrayList.get(position).getDay()` has returned null.

If you think it crashes at `eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure()`, you could try [TextUtils.isEmpty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) instead, which also checks for null:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure())){
    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.tvLieu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    holder.tvNom.setLayoutParams(params);
    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#227c97"));
} else {
    // also you should update tvDate, tvLieu, tvNom and cardView
    // or you would get weird behaviour when the view holder is being recycled
}
```

If you think it crashes at `eventsArrayList.get(position).getDay()`, you could use [TextUtils.equals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#equals(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
if (TextUtils.equals(eventsArrayList.get(position).getDay(), String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))
```

Most importantly, I'd not recommend `RecyclerView.scrollTo` in `onBindViewHolder`, it's a bad practice, you should perform this action else where. And maybe because you're trying to match a condition, and it can return null for other positions, so NPE occurs.

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer what i wanted to do works but i need to start 2 times the planning activity to make the recyclerview scroll to the position i want

Comment: I'm not too sure about you "need to start 2 times the planning activity" part..? If you're saying you have trouble scrolling the recycler view, you could try calling `recyclerView.postDelayed(()->recyclerView.scrollToPosition(desired_position), 300);` right after setting your adapter.

Comment: I mean i need to intent my actvity planning, go back to my mainactivity and re-intent my planning activity to make the ScrollToPosition work

Comment: And what you send doesn't work i don't know how to fix it but thanks for all you do for me =)

Comment: Oh, maybe create new question for it and see if there's anyone else could help. Good luck!